# SAME content of PDF have DIFFERENT hash values

Tags: hash, corda

Is it possible that same content of a pdf  have different HASH value ?

database value "Hello  World"   => convert into PDF =>generate HASH =>Save HASH into Database

Now,After one year

**scenario 1:** 
Generate HASH from Same PDF  => Generate HASH => compare generated HASH with saved Database HASH Value
Both Hash value will be same or different ?

**scenario 2:** 
Generate again New PDF 
database value "Hello  World"   => convert into New PDF =>generate HASH =>  compare generated HASH with saved Database HASH Value
Both Hash value will be same  or different ?

Is there any possibility that Both HASH will be different in CORDA Blockchain ?

Comment: Please update your question with code samples of the following: 1. How you are generating the pdf file, 2. How you are generating the hash of the pdf file.

Comment: No coding so far. This is general idea to ensuring integrity of pdf file e.g.   In our portal  a pdf file will generated and hash of file will be saved in Corda Blockchain , after some time pdf will be loaded again based on saved data in database (considering same data content) and then the Portal extracted the hash of that file and compared it against the hash saved in the Portal's Blockchain

Comment: Have you verified that the generated PDF files really are identical? Did you do a binary comparison on them?

Comment: not really. but i understand that if metadata is part of HASH then both hash will be different.

Answer (score 1):

Hash of a file is generated based on the entire file (including all metadata) not just the content.

Hence two file having similar content doesn't necessarily mean that they have the same digital fingerprint. There is no guarantee that two files with similar content would produce similar hashes.

Comment: If i generate HASH from PDF file and from Word File considering same content then there would be two different HASH. But generating PDF for the second time not WORD 
 file with considering same content then same HASH will be generated otherwise concept of hashing is nonsense. in this scenario META DATA should be same even after few year generating hash from PDF.

Comment: @deepak Metadata often includes a timestamp that says when the file was created. That certainly would change.